# Variance of weighted random permutations

Tags: probability, permutations

I am self-studying "Probability Models for Computer Science" by Sheldon Ross. This is question 12 from Ch 2.

A weighted random permutation of $1, \cdots, n$ with weights $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n$ is one whose first element is $j$ with probability $\lambda_j / \sum_i \lambda_i$, $j=1,\cdots,n$. If the first element in the permutation is $j$, then the next element is $i$ , $i \neq j$, with probability $\lambda_i / \sum_{k\neq j} \lambda_k$. In general, each subsequent element of the permutation will equal any value not yet appearing with a probability that is equal to the weight of that value divided by the sum of the weights of all those values that have not yet appeared in the permutation.

Find
a) the expected value and
b) the variance of the position of $i$ in a weighted random permutation.

So far, I have:

- Let $p_i$ be the position of $i$ in the weighted random permutation.
- Let $I_{i,j} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if i comes before j} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$
- $p_i = 1 + \sum_{j \neq i} I_{j,i}$
  $$
  \begin{array}
  \mathbf{E}[p_i] &= 1 + \sum_{j \neq i} E[I_{j,i}] \\
         &= 1 + \sum_{j \neq i} P(I_{j,i}) \\
         &= 1 + \sum_{j \neq i} \frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_i + \lambda_j}
  \end{array}
  $$

I tried calculating the variance by assuming that $I_{i,j}$s are independent, but this can be proven false with a simple example. Can someone help me calculate the variance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach so far is good. To find the variance of a sum of indicator variables, you need to find the expectation of a product of indicator variables. The product of the indicator variables of two events is the indicator variable of the intersection of the events (since the product is $1$ iff both events occur). So

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf{Var}(p_i)
&=&
\mathsf{Var}(p_i-1)
\\
&=&
\mathsf{Var}\left(\sum_{j\ne i}I_{j,i}\right)
\\
&=&
\mathsf E\left(\left(\sum_{j\ne i}I_{j,i}\right)^2\right)-\mathsf E\left(\sum_{j\ne i}I_{j,i}\right)^2
\\
&=&
\sum_{j,k\ne i\atop k\ne j}\left(\mathsf E\left(I_{jk,i}\right)-\mathsf E\left(I_{j,i}\right)\mathsf E\left(I_{k,i}\right)\right)+\sum_{j\ne i}\left(\mathsf E\left(I_{j,i}^2\right)-\mathsf E\left(I_{j,i}\right)^2\right)\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

where $I_{jk,i}$ is the indicator variable of the event that both $j$ and $k$ come before $i$. The probability for this is

$$
\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_i+\lambda_j+\lambda_k}\cdot\frac{\lambda_k}{\lambda_i+\lambda_k}+\frac{\lambda_k}{\lambda_i+\lambda_j+\lambda_k}\cdot\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_i+\lambda_j}=\frac{\lambda_j\lambda_k}{\lambda_i+\lambda_j+\lambda_k}\left(\frac1{\lambda_i+\lambda_k}+\frac1{\lambda_i+\lambda_j}\right)\;,
$$

so

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&
\sum_{j,k\ne i\atop k\ne j}\left(\mathsf E\left(I_{jk,i}\right)-\mathsf E\left(I_{j,i}\right)\mathsf E\left(I_{k,i}\right)\right)
\\
&=&
\sum_{j,k\ne i\atop k\ne j}\left(\frac{\lambda_j\lambda_k}{\lambda_i+\lambda_j+\lambda_k}\left(\frac1{\lambda_i+\lambda_k}+\frac1{\lambda_i+\lambda_j}\right)-\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_i+\lambda_j}\cdot\frac{\lambda_k}{\lambda_i+\lambda_k}\right)
\\
&=&
\sum_{j,k\ne i\atop k\ne j}\left(\frac{\lambda_j\lambda_k}{(\lambda_i+\lambda_j)(\lambda_i+\lambda_k)}\left(\frac{2\lambda_i+\lambda_j+\lambda_k}{\lambda_i+\lambda_j+\lambda_k}-1\right)\right)
\\
&=&
\lambda_i\sum_{j,k\ne i\atop k\ne j}\frac{\lambda_j\lambda_k}{(\lambda_i+\lambda_j)(\lambda_i+\lambda_k)(\lambda_i+\lambda_j+\lambda_k)}\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Together with

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{j\ne i}\left(\mathsf E\left(I_{j,i}^2\right)-\mathsf E\left(I_{j,i}\right)^2\right)
&=&
\sum_{j\ne i}\left(\mathsf E\left(I_{j,i}\right)-\mathsf E\left(I_{j,i}\right)^2\right)
\\
&=&
\sum_{j\ne i}\left(\mathsf E\left(I_{j,i}\right)\left(1-\mathsf E\left(I_{j,i}\right)\right)\right)
\\
&=&
\sum_{j\ne i}\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_i+\lambda_j}\cdot\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i+\lambda_j}
\\
&=&
\lambda_i\sum_{j\ne i}\frac{\lambda_j}{\left(\lambda_i+\lambda_j\right)^2}\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

this yields

$$
\mathsf{Var}(p_i)
=
\lambda_i\sum_{j\ne i}\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_i+\lambda_j}\left(\frac1{\lambda_i+\lambda_j}+\sum_{k\ne i,j}\frac{\lambda_k}{(\lambda_i+\lambda_k)(\lambda_i+\lambda_j+\lambda_k)}\right)\;.
$$

For equal weights, this reduces to the variance of the uniform distribution on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$,

$$\mathsf{Var}(p_i)=\frac{n^2-1}{12}\;.$$